# recursión en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la escuela en el que tengo una lista de materias,
pero estas materias tienen materias hijo (o previas) y así sucesivamente.

La idea es que cuando se haga un hover por la materia las materias previas cambien de color, y las previas de las previas también.

Así se define una materia

```
{"id": "Electronica",
        "hijo": ["math3", "math2", "math1"],
        "nombre":"Electrónica"}
```

donde hijo serían las previas.

Se realizaron dos funciones (una de estás recursiva)

```
function pintar(idpadre) {
if(!isfiltred){
    for (i = 0; i < materias.length; i++) {

        if (materias[i].id === idpadre && (materias[i].hijo.length > 0)) {

            for (j = 0; j < materias[i].hijo.length; j++) {

                if (materias[i].hijo[j] !== null) {
                    document.getElementById(materias[i].hijo[j]).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,99,71,0.5)";
                    document.getElementById(materias[i].hijo[j]).style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0.2rem rgba(220,20,60,0.5)";
                    pintarHijos(materias[i].hijo[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

function pintarHijos(cursoId){
    for (i = 0; i < materias.length; i++) {
        if (materias[i].id === cursoId) {
            if(materias[i].hijo !== null && materias[i].hijo.length > 0){
                for(j = 0; j < materias[i].hijo.length; j++){
                    document.getElementById(materias[i].hijo[j]).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(214, 132, 56,0.5)";
                    document.getElementById(materias[i].hijo[j]).style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0.2rem rgba(220,20,60,0.5)"
                    console.log("pinto")
                    pintarHijos(materias[i].hijo[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pero cuando la función pintar 2 llega a una materia sin previas (materia que tiene "[]" como hijo)
lanza una excepcion como si estuviara manejando un null

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hijo' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las variables que sirven de contador en los ciclos `for` se están declarando de forma global. Por esa razón la función `pintarHijos()` modifica esas variables cuando se ejecuta y al regresar a la función `pintar()` se produce el error porque los contadores tienen valores incorrectos.

**Solución:** declarar las variables con `let` para que sean locales.

```
for (let i = 0; i < materias.length; i++)
```

Comment: Gracias!!  Tu respuesta solucionó mi problema.